# .htaccess redirects - updated site (301 appropriate?)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I've run into a problem updating my site, the google search results show up links to the old page which are 404's now, some of them even containing deprecated content.

My question is about the use of 301's. The old page had deeply nested pages like the example below:

```
    www.site.com/category/subjects/subject_b.html
```

It shows up in google with a very specific description of 'subject_b', which is not optimal for my purposes.

The new layout I've been working on means that content that was once under '/category/subjects/subject_b' is now found in a single page (www.site.com/subjects.html), along with the hypothetical subject_a & subject_c.

Would I be wrong redirecting the old pages like this?

```
    redirect http://www.site.com/category/subjects/subject_a.html http://www.site.com/subjects.html
    redirect http://www.site.com/category/subjects/subject_b.html http://www.site.com/subjects.html
    redirect http://www.site.com/category/subjects/subject_c.html http://www.site.com/subjects.html
```

Also, how would I deal with pages that have google descriptions with content which is not on the new equavilient page?

I'd be happy if anyone could shed some light on this for me, or point me in a right direction as to where I can read more about it!

Answer (score 0):

> Would I be wrong redirecting the old pages like this?

You'd remove the `http://www.site.com` part. This should suffice:

```
Redirect 301 /category/subjects/subject_a.html /subjects.html
Redirect 301 /category/subjects/subject_b.html /subjects.html
Redirect 301 /category/subjects/subject_c.html /subjects.html
```

Or even:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/subjects/subject(.*) /subjects.html
```

to cover for all 3.

If you have multiple domains all pointing to the same document root and you actually need to match the path for a specific domain, you can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?category/subjects/subject(.*) /subjects.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick reply! Also: what's your take on the search result descriptions (would the google bot change these when it's been 301'd and i reindex through webmaster tools)?